# typo3 8.7.19 - images are always displayed in full page with

Tags: typo3-8.7.x

I have a problem with images and Typo3.
in the current version 8.7.19 my image 32x32px is always displayed in max width.
my content element ist "text and pics" and image orientation is "center below text" (Unten mittig) ..

see atachement[image]

same problem with "next to the text on the right" (Neben dem Text rechts)

[image: xx]
how can I change this?

Comment: How dos your image processing settings in the installtool look? Did you run the imageprocessing check? What was is the result?

Comment: Or could it be an simple CSS issue?

Comment: If you know whats wrong, please give an answer here!!!

Comment: Hello , I can not see and problems in my image configuration. "test setup" looks very good.

Comment: in my css, i found this:

`}
.gallery-item img, .gallery-item picture {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
figure img, figure picture {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`
please remember, I only use typo3 8.7 with bootstrap 10.0.2 in default configuration.

Comment: Hello - I found a typo3 constant:
plugin.bootstrap_package_contentelements.gallery.columns.1.class 

removing gallery-item-size-1 seems to fix the problem .. do you understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that deleting the value in

`plugin.bootstrap_package_contentelements.gallery.columns.1.class =`

solves the problem.